# Temp-to-Perm Question

Tags: professionalism, communication, career-development, work-life-balance

Ok.. so let's start with the fact that the staffing agency I work for is an unusual one. They told me when in a temp-to-perm position, like I am in now, that they keep you as a temporary employee until you have met your 90 day/3 month probationary period. Now... about the position. I absolutely love what I do. It's great work and the environment of the company is absolutely calming. I started working here under the temp agency on March 31, 2016. I met my 3 month probationary period Friday, July 1, 2016. My boss has already paid me for two holidays [which most companies don't do] and has told me if I need anything [even a day off] to let her know. During the three months I have been here I have only taken one day off. I took that day off due to having a fever of 102 degrees and feeling very sick. I notified my boss my email, work phone and cell phone. I have been to work 15 minutes early or more every single day. My question is... how can I professionally ask if there are new tasks I need to learn as well as tasks I need to improve on to help me get a permanent position? Also how can I make it to where she understands that I really want the permanent position? See.. I really need the extra time and money. My (2) children are about to start pre-k in a month and I am going to have to pay $162 a week for before and after care due to noone being close enough who can watch them every day while I work. So it is pretty crucial of me knowing because if I am not going to go permanent I am going to have to have a second job. My boss is the Vice President and she is the one I have to confirm my career with.

Comment: I'm confused. You were told to work 3 months as a temp until you would be hired as full time, but this hasn't happened? Is that the issue?

Comment: 3 months temp-to-perm or any time frame given to you, advertising these type of jobs are just approximately when they will need someone permanent. It is not a hard figure, set in stone. You just completed your 3 months. According to what you said, you did well. Wait for a few more days for your boss to come to you with a permanent offer. Your child may go to school and you may need extra money for that, but it is not the employer's concern. Until you have the perm position, you might need an additional job if you are strapped for it. Understand that you are not entitled to a perm position

Comment: Have you gone to your boss yet and asked?  A straight forward approach may be the best.

Comment: This needs some edit work because I can't find the real question in this wall of text. OP hasn't returned so this is another one-and-done. VTC, VTD

Answer (score 4):

> My question is... how can I professionally ask if there are new tasks
>   I need to learn as well as tasks I need to improve on to help me get a
>   permanent position?

Talk to your boss.

Something like "Hey, boss. Are there any new tasks I need to learn or tasks I need to improve on in order to get a permanent position here?" should work.

Comment: It's amazing the number of questions on this site that could simply be answered by "Talk to your boss..." or "Just ask..."